# how to create sympy fraction with square root in denomiator?

Tags: python, sympy

```
# From jupyter notebook
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

x1 = sympy.Rational(1, 2)
x2 = sympy.sqrt(2)

# ERROR: can't do this..
x3 = sympy.Rational(1, sympy.sqrt(2))

# ERROR: can't do this either
x4 = sympy.Rational(1, x2)
```

How to symbolically put sqrt in denominator of equation without using floating point numbers?

Comment: All of the uses I've seen for `sympy.Rational` where two values are given, you need to give it two integers.  If you want the rational closest to `1/sqrt(2)` you should provide that as the 1 argument. ie: `x3 = sympy.Rational(1/sympy.sqrt(2))`

Comment: Is the problem that you explicitly need it to be 1 / sqrt(2) not, e.g., sqrt(2) / 2? So you can't just do `1 / x2`?

Comment: that's a good point...

Answer (score 0):

When you need 1 / sqrt(2), do this:

```
x1 = 1 / sympy.sqrt(2)
```

when you need 1/2, do this:

```
x1 = sympy.Rational(1,2)
```

Don't do this:

```
x1 = sympy.Rational(1, sympy.sqrt(2))
```

Error.